# This scenario requires to use map Town01

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, carla

I am using Ubuntu16.04, CARLA 0.9.6  and the Scenario Manager 0.9.6. 
I have already opened an issue: https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/issues/1888

```
./CarlaUE4.sh /Game/Carla/Maps/Town01 -windowed -ResX=320 -ResY=240 -benchmark -fps=10
4.22.1-0+++UE4+Release-4.22 517 0
Disabling core dumps.
```

I am getting the error:

```
python scenario_runner.py --openscenario srunner/configs/FollowLeadingVehicle.xosc 
The CARLA server uses the wrong map!
This scenario requires to use map Town01
```

What am I doing wrong? Manuel_control.py does work after spawning some vehicles.

---

1) Similar Thread: https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/issues/1700 Is there a different path?

2)

```
export CARLA_ROOT=/home/user/Documents/prec_CARLA_0.9.6
export CARLA_SERVER=/home/user/Documents/prec_CARLA_0.9.6/CarlaUE4.sh
export ROOT_SCENARIO_RUNNER=/home/user/Documents/scenario_runner

$PYTHONPATH
 /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/user/Documents/prec_CARLA_0.9.6/PythonAPI/carla/:/home/user/Documents/prec_CARLA_0.9.6/PythonAPI/carla/agents/:/home/user/Documents/scenario_runner:/home/user/carla-ros-bridge/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/user/Documents/prec_CARLA_0.9.6/PythonAPI/carla/dist/carla-0.9.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag --reloadWorld fixed it!

```
python scenario_runner.py --openscenario srunner/configs/FollowLeadingVehicle.xosc --reloadWorld
```